# Families of graphs where the shortest path between vertices uniquely determines vertex pairs

Tags: graph-theory, terminology

Imagine a graph $G$ with unlabeled vertices and unlabeled edges, and where we have an arbitrary vertex pair $(v_1,v_2)$.  Let $k$ be the length of the shortest edge-wise path between $v_1$ and $v_2$.  If $G$ is an $N$-dimensional hypercube, I believe we can say that $k$ uniquely defines these vertices up to isomorphisms of the graph.

Is there a specific name for the family of graphs with this sort of property?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These are the [distance-transitive graphs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distance-transitive_graph).  Apparently the hypercube graphs are the simplest asymptotic families of such graphs, but other infinite families are known: e.g., the square [rook's graphs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rook%27s_graph).